# Defining an Infinite Product (Answered)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I have the following infinite series (of which the following are the $1^{st}, 2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ term

$$2^{b}$$

$$\big(2^{b}\big)ab+\big(2^{b}\big)a$$

$$\bigg(\big(2^{b}\big)ab+\big(2^{b}\big)a\bigg)ab+\bigg(\big(2^{b}\big)ab+\big(2^{b}\big)a\bigg)a$$

$$etc.$$

The pattern seems quite straightforward: it basically takes the previous value and multiplies it by $ab$ and $a$, and sums this.

I want to come up with a formula that describes the $n^{th}$ term, and evaluate it as $n->\infty$.

Also, some tips on how to evaluate it would be helpful. I believe the product must be convergent to evaluate it - but am not sure how to check for this.

---

values of a and b: $a>0,b>1$

Comment: what values do $a$ and $b$ take? also, are you interested in the limit of the sequence you are describing or the corresponding series? and why are you talking about a product even though you are describing a process of summing?

Comment: Ah sorry! The values of a>0, b>1. See also the later edits.

Comment: $2^b (ab+a)^{n-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $n$-th term is
$u_n$,
the
$n+1$-st term is
$u_{n+1}
=abu_n+au_n
=(ab+a)u_n
$.

Doing this $m$ times,
$u_{n+m}
=(ab+a)^mu_n
$.

Setting $n = 0$,
$u_m = (ab+a)^mu_0
$.
Since
$u_0 = 2^b$,
$u_m = 2^b(ab+a)^m
$.